# C# wpf export to Excel issue

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid

I have a dataGrid in my WPF application. I can export this dataGrid due to this good tutorial : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120480/Export-to-Excel-Functionality-in-WPF-DataGrid

My problem is : I get every column of my Object, and i'd want to display only the columns of my actual Datagrid, not every strings of my Object. One guy asked the question in this tutorial, he didn't get any answer. 
Also, I want to switch the order of my columns, so I found this snappet :

```
Excel.Range copyRange = _range.Range["D:D"];
        Excel.Range insertRange = _range.Range["A:A"];
        insertRange.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, copyRange.Cut());
```

The only problem is : It only works one time, I can switch A column to D but once it's done I can't move B to E for example ...

So I heard about MyXls and other librairies (I'm quoting this one cause that's a free one and I can only use free librairies for this project).

I'm a bit lost, I've been working on this for 2 days and I don't know what to do.

Do you have a great librairy for Excel import in WPF ? Or do you have a snippet to switch columns and especially (most important) display only the DataGrid row ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copying your list of objects into a smaller list of DTO objects that contain only the fields on the data grid?  That way, the export to Excel functionality would only iterate the fields from the datagrid because that's all the datagrid knows about.  I'd open a second question for the ordering / reordering of columns.

Comment: Hi josh, thanks for your answer. I tried to copy my ObservableCollection of myObject as an other ObservableCollection but I don't want to create a new object. I will try to use DTO then, even if I know nothing about it yet !